# TeamCity and download folders

Tags: maven, teamcity

We are running Java-Cucumber-Maven automated test scripts from TeamCity. Up to now this has worked very well but our current test requires that several .CSV files are downloaded for analysis by the script. There's a

```
ReadCsvFiles.java
```

file in our code and that dictates where the downloaded files are located....easy for running tests locally but we're having real problems with the path to the build agent in TeamCity..

```
public class ReadCsvFiles {

//public static String sFileLocation = "C:\\Users\\ankit.bisht\\Downloads\\";
public static String sFileLocation = "C:\\BuildAgent\\temp\\buildTmp\\";
 //public static String sFileLocation = "//users/redmayned//Downloads/";

public static void depositsHeldReports() throws Throwable {

    String csvFile = sFileLocation + "DepositsHeld.csv";

    CSVReader reader = null;
    try {

        reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        String[] column;
        boolean doesExist = false;
        while ((column = reader.readNext()) != null) {
```

The commented out entries are for local windows and local OSX. The middile one is just one of many options we've tried...all resulting in an error message;

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\DepositsHeld.csv (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Can anyone save my sanity please?

Thanks

David

Comment: Does the TeamCity server also run on Windows? Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Hi Sebastian. Yes as far as I know! Certainly the Build Agents are. Java is 10.0.1 b10. Looked on TeamCity and the entry there is showing jdk1.8.0_152

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Maybe this can help: https://www.sghill.net/how-do-i-make-cross-platform-file-paths-in-java.html
Since Java 7 you can use Paths to build somewhat platform independent paths for files and folders.